# JQuery Validation - Remove .checked class when is not 'success'

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

can you help me understand how to remove .checked class added with:

```js
success: function(label) {
    label.addClass("checked");
}
```

when the input is not 'success

Answer (score 0):

Check for the existence of the 'success' class

```
if (!$(input).hasClass('success')){
    label.removeClass('checked')
}
```